# Will MCP23017-E/SP be compatible with an ATtiny85? ATmega328P?

Tags: arduino, atmega, i2c, attiny, expander

I mainly want to also be able to use the same I/O expanders with `ATTiny85` projects since those chips have limited pins.

I will be doing the main prototyping on an ATmega328P ( Arduino UNO ).

Given that both of these are 8 bit, how do they deal with 16 bit resolutions from the [MCP23017](http://www.newark.com/microchip/mcp23017-e-sp/ic-i-o-expander-16bit-1-7mhz-dip/dp/31K2959?ost=MCP23017&categoryId=800000004673)?

[MCP23017/MCP23S17 Spec Sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/12179.pdf)

Comment: if someone is still interested in attiny85 and mcp23017 https://github.com/9glt/arduino-attiny85-mcp23017-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will work.  However, you may need to read over the datasheets to figure out how to talk to them.  Basically, the chip has a set of registers that you can access over the serial interface.  These registers control the pins (direction, level, etc.) as well as provide the input pin state.  To access all 16 pins, you would need to access two 8 bit registers, one for the lower 8 pins and one for the upper 8 pins.